# Progress bar when using Jupyter of Julia in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, progress-bar

In Julia, some amazing packages like `ProgressMeter` provide an easy API for displaying progress bars in the REPL. However, when it is used in the Jupyter from VScode, the whole process is printed out such as:

```
Progress:   4%|██                                       |  ETA: 0:06:05
Progress:   6%|███                                      |  ETA: 0:05:25
Progress:   8%|████                                     |  ETA: 0:04:56
```

Is there a way to let it perform exactly like in the REPL rather than printing out every progress, how should I adjust the settings in VScode?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this should just work, here's what it looks like for me in an IJulia Jupyter notebook (screenshot taken mid exectution):

[image]

and at the end:

[image]

Comment: I confirm this works. ProgressMeter states it might not work with version 1.2.0 (but this is a one dated to 2019)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried out your code and found that the problem probably only occurred in VScode. I have edited the question.

Comment: So you are talking about Jupyter notebooks in VSCode? In that case it's probably a case of stuff that just isn't working yet, the VSCode notebook support is relatively new. I don't think there's anything you can do about it, apart from maybe opening an issue on the Julia VSCode extension repo (might be an upstream problem though)